# libgit2: git_remote_create without apply_insteadof

Tags: libgit2

I'd like to use an equivalent of [git_remote_create_anonymous](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/0eca42304a10c9ad6170a38a440dfab8e354d38d/include/git2/remote.h#L73) 
function, but without applying `insteadof` url substitutions.
This is similar to `git_remote_create_detached` which states this explicitly

```
/**
 * Create a remote without a connected local repo
 *
 * Create a remote with the given url in-memory. You can use this when
 * you have a URL instead of a remote's name.
 *
 * Contrasted with git_remote_create_anonymous, a detached remote
 * will not consider any repo configuration values (such as insteadof url
 * substitutions).
 *
 * @param out pointer to the new remote objects
 * @param url the remote repository's URL
 * @return 0 or an error code
 */
GIT_EXTERN(int) git_remote_create_detached(
        git_remote **out,
        const char *url);
```

I could not find an equivalent API or combination of APIs that would get me this. Any ideas?

### Motivation

The use-case of it is to bypass any users global `~/.gitconfig` settings. For example, it's common to have

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

For example [CircleCI uses this approach](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2429#issuecomment-191370340).

Answer (score 1):

For the record, support for this been [added to libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/4667) (though it's not yet in a release), via a new `git_remote_create_with_opts` function, via the `GIT_REMOTE_CREATE_SKIP_INSTEADOF` flag. Thanks for suggesting it .

Comment: Now available in v0.28 !